# catkin_make package not found

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, tf-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to follow this tutorial  http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF  but after I catkin_make the package with this output:

```
Base path: /home/master/catkin_ws
Source space:
/home/master/catkin_ws/src Build
space: /home/master/catkin_ws/build
Devel space:
/home/master/catkin_ws/devel Install
space: /home/master/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in
"/home/master/catkin_ws/build"
####

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/master/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/master/catkin_ws/build/test_results

-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - robot_setup_tf
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'robot_setup_tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(robot_setup_tf)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/master/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/master/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

but when I try

> rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster

the sheel output is:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable
named tf_broadcaster below
/catkin_ws/build/robot_setup_tf/catkin_generated/stamps/robot_setup_tf
```

I'm a newbie in source devoloping soo I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66084/catkin_make-package-not-found/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me as if your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable is set wrong.  ROS should be looking in `/home/master/catkin_ws/devel`, not the `build` directory for your executables.

Did you remember to source the `devel/setup.bash` file to add the catkin workspace to your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?  More info at the bottom of [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) tutorial.

```
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-27**:
thanks a lot, it works, but now the other packages are not found. I create the catkin_ws inside the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and I don't remember how to set  both path as ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.Could you help me one more time?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-27**:
@danielq Please ask a full new question so that it can stand on it's own and help others with the new problem you have.

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-27**:
thanks for the suggestion @tfoote , I will do it.